# Gitlab Self Hosted Runner .yarn2 cache

Tags: gitlab, runner

The npm scripts in self hosted runner are not working. The problem seems to be in the yarn2 dependency cache.

Error:

```
$ yarn eslint
Usage Error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)
```

```
image: node:latest

.only: &only
  refs:
    - master
    - merge_requests
    - /^prod-.*/

.defaultJob: &defaultJob
  only:
    <<: *only
  tags:
    - opeq-runner

eslint:
  <<: *defaultJob
  stage: lints
  script:
    - yarn
    - yarn eslint

typecheck:
  <<: *defaultJob
  stage: lints
  script:
    - yarn
    - yarn typecheck
```

Runner config:

```
concurrent = 5
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "opeq-runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  id =
  token = ""
  token_obtained_at = 2023-10-09T22:14:01Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ansible/ansible"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Tried all the caching options in the yarn config, it seems to be a matter of runner config.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the full job output? Sometimes there's important information hidden in there that can lead to an unexpected solution.